# Why is my YES BOOL turned into a true bool by negator?

Tags: objective-c, boolean

I have the following code:

```objective-c
    // ...

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(mySel:) withObject:@YES];
}

// ...

- (void) mySel:(BOOL)suppressUserAlerts
{
    NSError*error;
    [obj doActionWithError:&error];
    if (!suppressUserAlerts && error) // line with breakpoint
    {
        [self alertOfError:error];
    }

    // ...
```

Now, even though I passed in `@YES`, `alertOfError:` is always called. So, naturally, I debugged it and added some watched expressions and breakpoints, and I found this nonsense:

[image: A screenshot of two expressions: <code>!suppressUserAlerts = (bool) true</code> and <code>suppressUserAlerts = (BOOL) YES</code>]

So, baffled, I ask: **why is `suppressUserAlerts` `YES`, and `!suppressUserAlerts` `true`?** And, more importantly, **How do I get the value I want?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@timgcarlson is right in his corrections.

Nevertheless, to *answer* your question:

You are actually passing an object by `@YES`. IF you now have the statement

```
if (!supressUserAlerts) {
```

you are actually testing for the non-existence of the object (equivalent to `supresseUserAlerts == nil`).
The `BOOL` declaration is more like a cast that only effects the debugger.

So your statement will always be true because `@YES` creates an object that not equals `nil`.

*EDIT*

To fix your bug in a proper way:

```
    // ...
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(mySel:) withObject:@YES];
}

- (void)mySel:(NSNumber *)suppressUserAlerts {
    NSError *error;
    [obj doActionWithError:&error];

    if (![suppressUserAlerts boolValue] && error) {
        [self alertOfError:error];
    }

    // ...
```

*EDIT II*

I think what you are seeing in the debugger is just the way it outputs the scalar boolean value (created by the `!` prefix) vs. the object bool.

Comment: Actually, using `if (!suppressUserAlerts)` is equivalent to using `if (suppressUserAlerts  == nil)` . The solution you provide is the correct one, however the problem is probably caused because of mismatching types of the input provided and the input needed (mySel: expects a `BOOL` whereas the passed argument is an `NSNumber`).

Comment: @halileohalilei thanks, was a typo in the morning ;-) Although, if you carefully read my corrected code, I declared the method with `NSNumber` instead `BOOL`, and my answer describes exactly the type problem (maybe not detailed enough)

Comment: yes I saw your code, that's why I said your solution is the correct one :) I just wanted to clarify the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(mySel:) withObject:@YES];
```

is passing an `NSNumber` instance. It is necessary to use an object rather than a scalar `BOOL` value here because `-performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` can only handle object-typed arguments (as "with**Object**:" suggests).

However, your method `-mySel:` take a `BOOL` parameter. Nothing in the framework will automatically unbox the `NSNumber` to convert it to the `BOOL`. Instead, your method is receiving an object pointer value but interpreting it as a `BOOL`.

Now, `BOOL` is an `unsigned char` or, on some architectures, a `bool`. So, only the low byte or low bit is examined by the "if" statement. A pointer to an `NSNumber` is quite likely to have a zero low byte or bit. Note that it doesn't matter what the value of the `NSNumber` object is. Only its address is being examined.

The debugger is probably confused. It may be doing the equivalent of "po <full 64-bit register value holding the object pointer>". So, even though your program is only examining the low byte or bit, the debugger is examining the full 64-bit value and treating it like an object pointer. Thus the debugger is misleading you as to what should happen.

As others have suggested, you can change your `-mySel:` method to take an `NSNumber*` rather than a `BOOL`. You will have to use the `-boolValue` method to examine that object's value.

However, you can also avoid this sort of issue by using Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) rather than `-performSelectorInBackground:withObject:`. Your code could be:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self mySel:YES];
});
```

There's no need to box the `YES` value into an object, so there's no problem with it being interpreted incorrectly in the method. And, if you did happen to have a type mismatch, the compiler can recognize it and warn you about it, which it can't do with `-performSelector...` methods.

Or, if you don't really need the `-mySel:` method except because you wanted to refer to it by a selector, you could directly inline its code into the block.

Comment: The GCD solution is really elegant, I didn't think of it

Comment: side question: will this issue be present in Swift, too?

Comment: I don't use GCD anymore, since it seems inconsistent how long it takes before it actually runs/deallocates my block, and these are time-sensitive operations.

Comment: Oh really?! Can you privide an example or post a GIST illustrating your observations?

Answer (score 0):

`BOOL` is not an object in Objective-C. One way to fix this error would be to pass the `BOOL` value (which is just a 0 or 1) via an `NSNumber` (an object).

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(mySel:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

- (void)mySel:(id)suppressUserAlerts {
    BOOL suppressUserAlertsBool = suppressUserAlerts.boolValue;
    // ...
}
```

**EDIT:** Note that you can still just pass `@YES` instead of `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]` as Cocoa will handle the conversion for you. I was just using `numberWithBool` to be more explicit.

Comment: You can leave him passing `@YES` but the param type must be `NSNumber`, I don't think `NSValue` has a `boolValue` method

Comment: Or better a `boolValue` property

Comment: Actually he *does* use an `NSNumber` kbject, but is treating it incorrectly.